# what is the protocol used in commuinication between ethereum blockchain nodes?

Tags: parity, network, protocol

Let's say that we have many blockchain nodes managed by parity clients.
what is the protocol used in communication between those nodes?

Answer (score 1):

The Ethereum wire protocol is called [ÐΞVp2p](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/%C3%90%CE%9EVp2p-Wire-Protocol). It consists of a DHT discovery part, derived from Kademlia, and a sync part, which is based on RLP-encoded encrypted messages.

Answer (score 1):

Peer-to-peer communications between nodes running Ethereum clients run using the underlying ÐΞVp2p Wire Protocol.
https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethereum-Wire-Protocol